# Possibility to opt-out remembered session

Tags: feature-request, logout

I would like the option for Stack Exchange sites to forget me when I leave the site or close the browser. This is to prevent others to log in with my account when using public computers or if your computer got stolen.

This could be realized with an option to "keep me logged in" or "remember me" when you log in, as you can do for a majority of sites such as Google, Facebook or Twitter, thus requiring a log in next time you visit the site.

Actually, according to The Open Web Application Security Project (cited below) the "remember me" feature should be avoided or not used at all.

> **Remember Me**
>
> Implementing remember me functionality can be incredibly
>   hard. Often software will just embed the username and password in
>   headers or cookies, or a hash or crypto blob of the same. Based upon
>   your risk profile, your application:
>
> - High value applications MUST NOT possess remember me functionality.
> - Medium value applications SHOULD NOT contain remember me functionality. If present, the user MUST opt-in to remember me. The
>     system SHOULD strongly warn users that remember me is insecure
>     particularly on public computers
> - Low value applications MAY include an opt-in remember me function. There should be a warning to the user that this option is insecure,
>     particularly on public computers. [1]

[1] https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication

Comment: *Obligatory answer to not use public computers for private stuff.*

Comment: But this also apply to say if your computer get stolen. That's why I never save password and like to always be required to sign in, even on my own computer. Keeps you remember those passwords too :)

Comment: @Time Traveling Bobby: The "obligatory answer" seems to better fit to a different question. SO is not "private" as nobody discusses here secret affairs. Logging in from a public computer is no big risk, yet, keeping the account secure makes sense.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can just use the private mode that is available in all of the recent  versions of the major browsers ([Chrome Incognito](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95464), [Firefox Private Browsing](http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Private%20Browsing) or [Internet Explorer InPrivate](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie-9/features/in-private)). This will log you out once you close the browser, and it will also prevent your browser history and some other stuff from being saved on that computer.

This won't protect you from other attacks, e.g. someone that managed to install a keylogger on the public computer will still be able to recover your password and log into your SO account.